# MATLAB: Extracting indices from 3D matrix for another 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have two 3D matrices `A` and `B`,  of the same size and another 3d matrix `I` of the same size containing some indices corresponding to the first dimension of `A`. I want to do something like `A(I)/B(I)`.

Specifically, `A(I(x,y,z),y,z)` divide it by `B(I(x,y,z),y,z)` for all of `x,y,z`.
How do I do it quickly maybe using `repmat` or `sub2ind` or simply logical indexing?

I know how to do this for 2D matrices very efficiently. If there was no `z` dimension I would do:

```
dum_i = I+(x_size+1).*repmat(0:(y_size-1), x_size+1, 1);  % Create a linear index
C= A(dum_i)./B(dum_i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both A and B are of the same size, I assume you want the element-wise division `./`

```
%Some random test data
A=rand(3,4,5);
B=rand(size(A));
I=zeros(size(A));
for d2=1:size(I,2)
    for d3=1:size(I,3)
        I(:,d2,d3)=randperm(size(I,1));
    end
end
%end of test data

%Second and third dimension are to be indexed directly, use ind2sub to genertae matching indices
[~,I2,I3]=ind2sub(size(A),1:numel(A));
%Generate a linear index, which does "I(x,y,z),y,z"
LI=sub2ind(size(A),I(:),I2(:),I3(:));
%Make the index the right shape:
LI=reshape(LI,size(A));
%Now linear indexing can be used to permute A and B in the intended way.
C=A(LI)./B(LI);
```

To further improve the performance you could:

- Replace the `ind2sub` line with some repmat expression.
- Do "C=A/B,C=C(I)". Wich would be `C2=A./B;C2=C2(LI);`

I guess both will improve the performance, but running some other computations I can't bemchmark anything at the moment.

Comment: this is just too slow... Can you write it with the repmat function?

Comment: For two dimensional matrices this works super fast, I don't know how to do for 3D matrices: dum_i = i+(dim1+1).*repmat(0:(dim2-1), dim1+1, 1);  C=A(dum_i )./B(dum_i )

Comment: What sizes of 2d and 3d matrices and what Version of MATLAB did you use?

Comment: R2019b, and I need to do this procedure a million times for matrices of dimension 100x100. See my edit in the question maybe that would help you.

Comment: So what are the dimensions of your 3d matrix? 100x100x1000000?